# Kirchhoff plate equation (vanishing parameter) (paper reference)

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Today I would like to ask not an specific question, but only a reference.

Would someone know where can I find papers about the Kirchhoff plate equation of the for $u_{tt}-\gamma \Delta u_{tt} + \Delta^2 u = f$, more specifically about the energy functional related to this equation in a situation where we want to vanish the parameter $\gamma$?

My advisor talked to me very quickly about this (she was in a hurry) and I would like to find and read some papers of even some books about this specific case of the Kirchhoff plate equation.

Please, if you can help me I would be very glad.

Thanks very much in advance guy.

Comment: "where we vanish the parameter $\gamma$" so the inhomogeneous wave equation? What is the domain?

Comment: @qbert when I say vanish I mean take the limit with $\gamma \to 0$ in a suitable norm. I don’t know about the domain, we talked very very vaguely. I just wanted to read about.

Comment: The equation you wrote looks like membrane rather than Kirchhoff plate. In any case, I would recommend "Vibration of Continuous Systems" by S. Rao. He both provides Newton and variational approaches (energy functionals) for the equations.